# When is the serialize and deserialize passport method called? What does it exactly set?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, mongoose, passport.js

We have two types of Users, Admin and general Users.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('Sear');
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log(id);
  console.log("Deser");
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    if(err) done(err);
    if(user){
      done(null, user);  
    }else{
       vendorUser.findById(id, function(err, user){
        if(err) done(err);
        done(null,user);
       });
    }
  });
});
```

Console.log gets outputted frequently (even on a single API request) with the text

> Deser

What do both the functions exactly do? A detailed answer is appreciated. 
TIA.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Serialization and deserialization are important concept. **To serialize an object means to convert its state to a byte stream so way that the byte stream can be reverted back into a copy of the object.**

**In a typical web application, the credentials used to authenticate a user will only be transmitted during the login request. If authentication succeeds, a session will be established and maintained via a cookie set in the user's browser.**

Each subsequent request will not contain credentials, but rather the unique cookie that identifies the session. **In order to support login sessions, Passport will serialize and deserialize user instances to and from the session.**

In the code that you have written, only the user ID is serialized to the session. When subsequent requests are received, this ID is used to find the user, which will be restored to `req.user`.

In order to give developers freedom to user whichever database they want, whatever data they want to serialize, they can do it in their own way, the serialization and deserialization logic is left to us to implement.

Comment: where does `user.id` come from? In most mongoose models I see for users  there are fields like: `_id`, `name`, `password` etc. Are the letters `id`arbitrary. can I use  `done(null, user.cat);`?

Comment: In MongoDB, documents stored in a collection require a unique _id field that acts as a primary key. MongoDB uses ObjectIds as the default value for the _id field if the _id field is not specified; i.e. if a document does not contain a top-level _id field, the MongoDB driver adds the _id field that holds an ObjectId. i would recommend you to read [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/). Serialisation/ deserialization is basically to do with object itself rather than individual values so try not to do **user.cat**, serializing **user** would be right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I knew what you wrote about `_id` I just think that it is weird in documentation for passport and in tutorials they mostly use  `user.id` and there is no `id` field in the document . Do you understand why I think that is weird? and also are implying that instead of using `user.id` I can use `done(null, **user**);` just user? or maybe `user.name` if there is a name field.

Comment: Where does the _user_ from _serialiseUser(function(user, done) { ... })_ come from ?

Answer (score 17):

`serializeUser` is the method that is called on the login request(during the authentication) and if login is successful then it decides what user information should get stored in the session and a cookie is sent to the browser for the same to maintain the session.

```
// Only during the authentication to specify what user information should be stored in the session.
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log("Serializer : ", user)
    done(null, user.id);
});
```

The above snippet will save the user.id field to the session and cookie.

`deserializeUser` is the method that is called on all subsequent request and is called by the `passport.session` middleware. It enables us to load additional user information on every request. This user object is attached to the request as req.user making it accessible in our request handling.

[Here is](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/) the article that explains it flow very well

Comment: Why is his serializeUser being called on every request, it should be only deserializeUser ??

Comment: @SurajJain, serializeUser will be called only while authenticating, For next requests, deserializeUser is called.