# bcrypt error with passport and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, bcrypt

Bcrypt is throwing an `Incorrect arguments` error which I traced back to this function in `user.js`

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = (candidatePassword, callback) => {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this, (err, isMatch) => {
    console.log('candidatePassword= ', candidatePassword, '&  this= ', this);
    if (err) { return callback(err); }
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};

   /* 
     candidatePassword=  bird
     this=  {}
     this.password=  undefined */
```

The user object is coming back as an empty object, and therefore `this.password` is undefined. I assume the `this` parameter in bcrypt.compare refers to the `userSchema` instance. The userSchema is declared in `passport.js`

```
const passport = require('passport');
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config');

var localOptions = {
  usernameField: 'email',
};

// Verifies user by checking if a password matches the specified email during signin
var localStrategy = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function (email, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ email:email.toLowerCase()}, function (err, user) {
    console.log('/passport.js/localStrategy- user object: ', user)
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
    user.comparePassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {
      console.log('/passport.js/localStrategy- password: ', password)
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!isMatch) { return done(err, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  });
}); 

// ... jwt strategy ...

passport.use(localStrategy);

/* 
  user object:  { _id: 58a1018dc3f89eb5955b8638,
  email: 'bird@bird.com',
  password: '$2a$10$lAJ9hoGKt9ggfk1TISfkOedxDIs/waLB5e4PccHAKt286XCKCY0/q',
  __v: 0 } */
```

I'm not sure quite what the issue as it seems a user object is returned with an encrypted password field from mongodb, and `user.comparepassword()` is called...

I signed the user up with the same Schema object as well.

Any help / tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only setting up your model so that it pulls in the candidatePassword but never finds the stored password from the database. Since this is returning an empty object, either the email is not being matched or the password is not being compared to what is stored. Try simplifying the comparePassword function and adding 'sync' to the bcrypt.compare which removes the need for a callback.

*In models:*

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = (candidatePassword) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, this.password);
};
```

Comment: you might also be missing the serialize and deserialize part

[Checkout this explaination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691215/when-is-the-serialize-and-deserialize-passport-method-called-what-does-it-exact)

Comment: Hi Clay! In passport.js my code pulls in the user object. The text from the the console.log statement is commented in the bottom. 

Since I call user.comparePassword in that method I assume that the variables can be accessed in user.js by the bcrypt.compareSync through using `this` as an argument. 

Is there a reason I can't pass the object once I've successfully pulled it in? Thank you